# Question concerning Julia/Mandelbrot set software

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

Hey guys I'm studying the Mandelbrot set, specifically this Julia set $Q(z) = z^2 - 1 $ and I'm trying to find NONREAL points that become eventually fixed at the fixed points (pre image).  I was wondering if there is a software that can iterate backward from a point on a Julia/Mandelbrot set so I can find these points graphically!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed points are $\dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.  The inverse images of these that are not fixed points are $\dfrac{-1 \mp \sqrt{5}}{2}$.  The inverse images of 
$\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ are $\pm \frac{i}{2} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}-2}$.

As for software: any of the standard mathematical software systems should do fine. Maple, Mathematica, Matlab, Sage, ...

Comment: Thank you Mr.Israel, can you tell me the process of how you obtain the preimages?

Comment: To solve $z^2 - 1 = b$: $z = \pm \sqrt{b+1}$.

Comment: Yes, of course!! I learned that in class a month ago.  I just forgot about it!  Thank you so much!